# injecting an enum as a dependency fails with IllegalArgumentException, probably due to proxying

Tags: java, spring, enums, proxy, illegalargumentexception

I have a Spring bean which expects among one of it's constructor parameters an enum. The enum is created inside the context with

```
@Bean
public MyEnum stage() {
    return MyEnum.VALUE1; /// actually here is some logic implemented to determin what enum value should get returned.
}
```

When I start up the ApplicatioContext I get the following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [MyBean]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
// .... more stuff
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
... 47 more
```

I assume this is because Spring wraps the enum in a proxy, which I need to enable AOP. But I don't need a proxy around the enum.

**Questions**:

1. Am I correct that the proxying of the enum is causing this problem?
2. How can I avoid this problem? One approach would be to disable proxying for the enum, but how would I do that?

Comment: Does the enum have behavior or just its value?

Comment: @chrylis it has one additional immutable property, but nothing else.

Comment: This looks like a bug; Spring clearly shouldn't be trying to instantiate an enum. I recommend filing against SPR.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the given information but I'd stickt to the side of a user error until further evidence. First, the exception doesn't even mention `MyEnum` at all. How would an enum without an interface be proxied at all? CGlib would already bark here. Please add the complete exception (maybe in a Gist, so that we can extract the relevant parts). Invalid proxying usually causes a different exception, no qualifying dependency being found for an injection point. What does the injection point actually look like? What does your proxying configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

Based on @chrylis comment, I assume (at least for now) that there is no "proper" way to fix this.

As a workaround I don't autowire my bean but create it explicit in the context and calling the logic to determine the correct enum directly. Since there are view places where I need the enum this works at least for me.

If I find time I will file a bug and update the answer with the link to it